# SQL Server : Subselect where IS NULL THEN 'VALUE'

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to return a string result when a value `IS NULL` in SQL Server.

An example of what I am doing is below. This is a sub select query...

```
SELECT 
    stockitems.code AS StockCode, 
    stockitems.description AS 
ShortDescription,
    (SELECT 
         CASE remaining 
            WHEN NULL 
               THEN 'NO LEVEL' 
            ELSE remaining 
         END 
     FROM StockItemAlertLevels  
     WHERE StockItems.ID = StockItemAlertLevels.StockItemID) AS RemainingLevel
FROM
    stockitems
WHERE 
    StockItems.Attribute1 = '1'
ORDER BY 
    StockItems.Code
```

No matter what I do, I cannot get the output result of the subselect to change if the result is `NULL`. Not all returned results from the SELECT statement will have returned results in the subselect - this is where I need the set the output to "NO LEVEL". The subselect will never return more than one result.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: You're close - you need to write `CASE WHEN remaining IS NULL THEN ...`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT si.code As StockCode, si.description AS ShortDescription,
       (SELECT COALESCE(remaining, 'NO LEVEL')     
        FROM StockItemAlertLevels sal
        WHERE si.ID = sal.StockItemID
       ) as RemainingLevel
FROM stockitems si
WHERE si.Attribute1 = '1'
ORDER BY si.Code;
```

I suspect, though, that your problem is not that `remaining` is `NULL`, but that there are no matches.  You can move the `COALESCE()` outside the subquery, but I would propose a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT si.code As StockCode, si.description AS ShortDescription,
       COALESCE(remaining, 'NO LEVEL') as RemainingLevel
FROM stockitems si LEFT JOIN
     StockItemAlertLevels sal
     ON si.ID = sal.StockItemID
WHERE si.Attribute1 = '1'
ORDER BY si.Code;
```